# Integration - Primitives - Antiderivatives

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

Please help to calculate:
$$\int\sqrt {{r}^{2}-{x}^{2}}{dx},\quad x\in[0,r]$$
Do any method of trigonometric substitution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the substitution $x=r\sin t$.

Comment: Good!. Thanks so much!

Comment: @mathsalomon: You are welcome!

Comment: For future reference.  That difference of squares may remind you of a certain right triangle.  Use it to find a good substitution to use.

Answer (score 0):

Or use the substitution x = r cosh t if you like calculus on the complex plane.

Comment: Hadamard said, "Le plus court chemin entre deux vérités dans le domaine réel passe par le domaine complexe."  This is an example where that quote is not apropos.